# mysqli_stmt_execute() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to save data from an HTML form into database `wordpress` table: `wp_testdb` using Prepared Statements method, But I am getting error against line `mysqli_stmt_execute();`

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
> Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['BtnSubmit'])){
    include_once 'dbConnection.php';

    if($conn -> connect_error) {
        die("connection failed:".$conn-> connect_error);
    }
    
    $date           = $_POST['date'];   
    $select_bank    = $_POST['select_bank'];
    $entry_type     = $_POST['entry_type'];
    $income_cat     = $_POST['income_cat'];
    $amount         = $_POST['amount'];
        

    $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_testdb (data_one, data_two, data_three, data_four, data_five) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
            echo "SQL Error !!";
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $date, $select_bank, $entry_type, $income_cat, $amount);
        mysqli_stmt_execute();
    }
}
```

dbConnection.php has below data:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";    
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "wordpress";
    
$conn= mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

Any suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: [Procedural style](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php): `bool mysqli_stmt_execute ( mysqli_stmt $stmt )`.  You forgot to add the $stmt to the execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend using the object oriented interface instead of the procedural. Both will work - however, all the procedural functions require the connection or statement object to be the first parameter.

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.execute), you need to pass the statement-object, in your case `$stmt`, as a parameter.

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

This function returns a boolean, which you can check if the query was successful or not.

```
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
        echo "SQL Error !!";
        error_log(mysqli_error($conn));
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $date, $select_bank, $entry_type, $income_cat, $amount);
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        // Query succeeded!
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Query failed. Log it, and do something?
        error_log(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
    }
}
```